# In Eagle board editor, how to remove origin mark?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

In Eagle board editor, how to remove origin mark?

Once set, I can move it, but can't remove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type "mark;" into the command bar. Press enter.

This toggles the mark. If you type it again the mark will reappear where you last had it.